# How to make my Binary_Search method work well?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I tried to create a Binary_Search method using c#
the method works well only when the array elements are in range of 8 elements
How can I make this simple algorithm works for the given array?
It displays "target was found: 16" when the expected answer is 17

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Algorithm
{
class Program
{
    //A method to search for a targeted number inside a sorted array
    public static int Binary_Search(int[] array,int target)
    {
       int first = 0;
       int last = array.Length - 1;
        while (first < last)
        {
            int midpoint = (first + last) / 2;
            if (array[midpoint] == target)
            {
                return midpoint;
            }
            else if (array[midpoint] < target)
            {
                first = midpoint + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                last = midpoint - 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    //A method to call in to print the targeted number if it was found
    public static void verfiy(int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target was not found");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target was found: {0}", index);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 };
        int t = 17;
        int result = Binary_Search(array,t);
        verfiy(result);
        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The algorithm works correctly, since `17` is at index `16`, which is the printed value

Comment: my bad I didn't explain well, when I entered 18 as a target number the answer was target was not found...now i got it why because i didn't put  "=" inside while loop condition

Comment: thnx bro, but may I ask you if we could do the same thing using cpp?

Comment: Just to ensure you are aware of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Kirollos you mean implement binary search using C++?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes, I tried to do so but since cpp doesn't have a Length method, I used sizeof() which didn't give me the correct calculations

Comment: @Aldert thnx a lot

Comment: @Kirollos you can use vectors in C++

Comment: @AbhinavMathur okay thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` condition should be `first <= last` instead of `first < last`. Also, return a negative number (e.g. `-1`) if item is not found (because `0` means that item is found at index `0`).

Here is the fixed code:

```
public static int Binary_Search(int[] array, int target)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = array.Length - 1;
    while (first <= last)
    {
        int midpoint = (first + last) / 2;
        if (array[midpoint] == target)
        {
            return midpoint;
        }
        else if (array[midpoint] < target)
        {
            first = midpoint + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            last = midpoint - 1;
        }
    }

    // item is not found, return -1
    return -1;
}
```